# jQuery: Array Element Incorrectly Updates inside ForLoop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, for-loop

I have a confusion and I can't get it why the result of this code (when executed) is incorrect.

I have 2 arrays of object (temparray1, temparray2). Basically, I need to store the elements of temparray1 to temparray2 then update the values using a for loop.

```
var temparray1 = [{title:"hi1",name:"name1",age:1},{title:"hi2",name:"name2",age:2},{title:"hi3",name:"name3",age:3}];
var temparray2 = [];

for(var aaa =0; aaa < temparray1.length; aaa++){ 
    temparray2.push(temparray1[aaa]);
    var len =   temparray2.length - 1;
    temparray2[len].color = "blue";
    temparray2[len].gender = "girl";

    temparray2.push(temparray1[aaa]);
    len =   temparray2.length - 1;
    temparray2[len].color = "red";
    temparray2[len].gender = "boy";
}
```

The results I'm expecting is:

```
temparray2 = [
    {title:"hi1",name:"name1",age:1,color:"blue",gender:girl},
    {title:"hi1",name:"name1",age:1,color:"red",gender:boy},
    {title:"hi2",name:"name2",age:2,color:"blue",gender:girl},
    {title:"hi2",name:"name2",age:2,color:"red",gender:boy},
    {title:"hi3",name:"name3",age:3,color:"blue",gender:girl},
    {title:"hi3",name:"name3",age:3,color:"red",gender:boy}
];`
```

But the actual result I get is that the color and gender of all items in temparray2 become 'red' and 'boy' respectively. Also, the value of the current item in temparray1 updates like temparray1[0] = {title:"hi1",name:"name1",age:1,color:"red",gender:boy}. But I do not intend to update temparray1 (the first array.).

Please let me know your thoughts about this. It's very confusing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you're pushing the whole object, not copying an object - so any changes to that object affect everywhere that it's referenced.

Comment: understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make deep copy of the objects or else changing the property of one object will affect the other if they are shallow copied.

As your object is JSON safe you can use

```
var newObj = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( someObj ) );
```

can be serialized to a JSON string and then re-parsed to an object with the same structure and values.

There can be other solutions involving `Array.prototype` methods  like `reduce`. Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var temparray1 = [{
  title: "hi1",
  name: "name1",
  age: 1
}, {
  title: "hi2",
  name: "name2",
  age: 2
}, {
  title: "hi3",
  name: "name3",
  age: 3
}];
var temparray2 = [];

for (var aaa = 0; aaa < temparray1.length; aaa++) {
  temparray2.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temparray1[aaa])));
  var len = temparray2.length - 1;
  temparray2[len].color = "blue";
  temparray2[len].gender = "girl";

  temparray2.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temparray1[aaa])));
  len = temparray2.length - 1;
  temparray2[len].color = "red";
  temparray2[len].gender = "boy";
}

console.log(temparray2);
```

Comment: Great! It worked perfectly. I understand it now. Thank you so much.